# Take the best value in dataframe which have multiple same datas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have this `df`:

```
                   score
0    a    b    c    0.7
1    a    b    c    0.7
2    b    c    d    0.8
3    c    d    e    0.9
4    c    d    e    0.9
5    d    e    f    0.8
```

I want to take values which have the best score, but there are more than one datas. And I want to take the last of the best (based on example, means row 4). Can you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want max and last per group (a,b,c,d,e,f)?

Comment: In my data, `a,b,c,d,e,f` are float numbers. They are different, and not in order. In that question, I represent 
`df` more simple. @BERA

Comment: I wish the code can returns values in row 4

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You can `loc` to find the largest by `score`, then `iloc` to select the last row:

```
res = df.loc[df['score'] == df['score'].max()]\
        .iloc[-1]

print(res)

score    0.9
Name: (4, c, d, e), dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` method in order to find max score.

```
max_score = df['score'].max()
```

Then select rows with max score.

```
df = df[df.score == max_score].iloc[-1]
```

Output

```
               score
4  c   d   e    0.9
```

Comment: Why not directly `max_score = df['score'].max()`. That whole thing can be a single line really.. `df = df[df['score'] == df['score'].max()]`

Comment: What if I want to get only one row? Row number 4?

Comment: Just use `iloc` method.